# How do I get database from Firebase Realtime Database for the first time the android app is installed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I know how I can add listeners on database references to detect when there's a change in the data and retrieve that data. But I can't seem to find out how I can get data from firebase when the app is first installed on the user's device. Its not going to happen that the user's installs the app and the data is going to change. How do I get the data without triggering the listeners for this scenario?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain further, I cannot understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners are triggered once when the listener is attached, and once when the relevant event happens.

So, just by creating a `ValueEventListener`, you'll get a snapshot of all its current data (and you'll get it every time you attach, not just once after you install the app).

There's more in the documentation about how to [listen for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events), but the specifically relevant text is:

> You can use the onDataChange() method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event. This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

This is also true for `ChildEventListener`s, via the `onChildAdded` method.  It is called for all items that exist, then once each time an item is actually added.  See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. I missed this entirely and only called the listeners when I did an operation on the data. I changed the code to attach the listeners when the app first starts and I'm getting the data.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question of how to get data when an app is first installed.  This answers the question of how to get data after an app is launched, but that's different than automatically doing something on first install, before the user launches it.